# Validation not worked on kendoUI multiselect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, data-annotations

I am creating a form by using MVC4.
Here i used kendo multiselect and try to validate through model annotation.

My Code is :

```html
@model WEBAPP._2012.Models.DeviceInventory.DeviceTechnologyModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Device_TechnologyInventory", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "onSuccessAddTechnology" })) { @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Name)</td>
    <td class="editor-field" width="160px;">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alias)</td>
    <td class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alias) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alias)
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Vendors)/td>
      <td class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model=>model.Vendors) .Name("Vendors").Placeholder("Select") .BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.VendorList, "Value", "Text")) ) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Vendors)
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="CreateWrp">
  <input type="submit" value="Create " class="btn-success"/>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset " class="btn-primary" />
</div>
```

My model is :

```
    public class DeviceTechnologyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Device Technology")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Alias")]
        public string Alias { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Device vendors")]
        public List<string> Vendors { get; set; }
    }
```

When i clicked on Submit button validation error message are appear on both "Name" and "Alias" field but not on field "Vendors".

I do not want to use `javascript` validation.

Comment: http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/13-08-29/handling-server-side-validation-errors-in-your-kendo-ui-grid

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the Value not a list object.

You may need to make below changes in your model:

```
public class DeviceTechnologyModel
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Device Technology")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Alias")]
        public string Alias { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Device vendors")]
        public int VendorId { get; set; }

        public List<string> Vendors { get; set; }
}
```

In your View:

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Vendors)/td>
      <td class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model=> model.VendorId)
                      .Name("Vendors").Placeholder("Select")
                      .BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.VendorList, "Value", "Text"))) 
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VendorId)
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Make sure when you submit the Form the `VendorId` property holds any value or not.

If it has nothing the validation should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No still it is not working. By inspecting element, I found kendo hide the <select> tag. and here model validation message appear on select tag. like..... <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Device vendors must be a number." data-val-required="*" id="VendorId" multiple="multiple" name="VendorId" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: none;"class="input-validation-error">

Comment: Looks like you are not passing the `int` (number) value. Make your model property as string and try. **Ex:** `public string VendorId { get; set; }`